# Navigation bar positioning

Tags: css, html

I would like to know how can I correct this issue, where the navigation bar is wrong positioned (it should be inside the margin lines and at the bottom of the header, as shown in [this](http://i.gyazo.com/fd5d66f7c7da42671871739c226cdf71.png) image).

The code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Homepage</title>
<style type="text/css">
html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

#container
{
 margin: 0 auto;
 background: #FFF;
 width: 100%;
}

header
{
 height: 180px;
 padding: 1% 1%;
 background-color: #22272A;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

title
{
 color: #FFF;
 margin: 0 auto;
 position: absolute;
 left: 20%;
 top: 2%;
 font-size: 48px;
 font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
}

nav { position: relative; }   
nav ul { display: inline-block; }  
nav ul li
{
 list-style: none;
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
 float: left;
 padding: 10px;
 text-align: center;
}

nav ul li .active
{
 color: #3479FA;
 background: #FFF; 
 border: 1px solid white;
 border-radius: 5px;
 padding: 10px;
}

nav ul li a
{
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #FFF;
 line-height: 30px;
 width: 40px; 
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">
     <header>
      <title>Sample Text</title>
            <nav>
             <ul>
                 <li class="active"><a href="bla.html" class="active">bla</a></li>
                    <li><a href="bla.html">bla</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

PD: The text is not being shown using this "compiler", but it works on my browser when I run it locally.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Side note, the `<title>` element must be in the head of a document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will align the ul to the bottom of the nav:

```
header {
    position: relative;
}

nav {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain what does this snippet do exactly? I have an important mental mess with positionattribute.

Comment: position: relative says "make this container 1. have a position relative to where it is now (e.g. top: 2px would push it down 2px from its normal layout position) and 2. allow absolutely-positioned children inside it to have their absolute positions relative to it instead of the window."

The position: absolute on the nav says "position this element absolutely relative to either the window or a parent container with position: relative (in this case, header)." bottom: 0 (combined with above) means, put it at the absolute bottom.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Homepage</title>
<style type="text/css">
html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

#container
{
 margin: 0 auto;
 background: #FFF;
 width: 100%;
}

header
{
 height: 180px;
 padding: 1% 1%;
 background-color: #22272A;
 margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;/*set this to relative because nav will be absolute*/
}

title
{
 color: #FFF;
 margin: 0 auto;
 position: absolute;
 left: 20%;
 top: 2%;
 font-size: 48px;
 font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
}
/*because we want it to start from the bottom*/
nav { position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0; width: 100%} 
/*set max width of you nav, margin 0 auto to center it */  
nav ul {position: relative;width: 100%; max-width: 480px; margin: 0 auto}  
nav ul li
{
 list-style: none;
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
 float: left;
 padding: 10px;
 text-align: center;
}

nav ul li .active
{
 color: #3479FA;
 background: #FFF; 
 border: 1px solid white;
 border-radius: 5px;
 padding: 10px;
}

nav ul li a
{
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #FFF;
 line-height: 30px;
 width: 40px; 
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">
     <header>
      <title>Sample Text</title>
            <nav>
             <ul>
                 <li class="active"><a href="bla.html" class="active">bla</a></li>
                    <li><a href="bla.html">bla</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are pushing the Sample Text thus, you need to push nav too... Run this code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Homepage</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    html,
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    #container {
      margin: 0 auto;
      background: #FFF;
      width: 100%;
    }
    header {
      height: 180px;
      padding: 1% 1%;
      background-color: #22272A;
      margin: 0px auto;
    }
    span {
      color: #FFF;
      margin: 0 auto;
      position: absolute;
      left: 20%;
      top: 2%;
      font-size: 48px;
      font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    }
    nav {
      position: relative;
      top:60%;
      left:12%
    }
    nav ul {
      display: inline-block;
    }
    nav ul li {
      list-style: none;
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 10px;
      text-align: center;
    }
    nav ul li .active {
      color: #3479FA;
      background: #FFF;
      border: 1px solid white;
      border-radius: 5px;
      padding: 10px;
    }
    nav ul li a {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #FFF;
      line-height: 30px;
      width: 40px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <header>
      <span>Sample Text</span>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li class="active"><a href="bla.html" class="active">bla</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="bla.html">bla</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Homepage</title>
<style type="text/css">
html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

#container
{
 margin: 0 auto;
 background: #FFF;
 width: 100%;
}

header
{
 height: 180px;
 padding: 1% 1%;
 background-color: #22272A;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

title
{
 color: #FFF;
 margin: 0 auto;
 position: absolute;
 left: 20%;
 top: 2%;
 font-size: 48px;
 font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
}

nav { position: relative; }   
nav ul { display: inline-block; }  
nav ul li
{
 list-style: none;
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
 float: left;
 padding: 10px;
 text-align: center;
}

nav ul li .active
{
 color: #3479FA;
 background: #FFF; 
 border: 1px solid white;
 border-radius: 5px;
 padding: 10px;
}

nav ul li a
{
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #FFF;
 line-height: 30px;
 width: 40px; 
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">
     <header>
      <title>Sample Text</title>
            <nav>
             <ul>
                 <li class="active"><a href="bla.html" class="active">bla</a></li>
                    <li><a href="bla.html">bla</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```